# Python Web-scraping for Review

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I need to scrape for the Review on the Nike Website.

I successfully extract the Class for the review but the Review itself is inside a .

My code is below:

*res = requests.get("https://www.nike.com/fr/t/polo-coupe-slim-polo-pour-kfhFZM/BQ4461-482")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

product = soup.select(".review.mb10-sm")

for item in soup.select(".review.mb10-sm"):
print(item.text)*

[Out]:
**"Summer polo shirtA L. - 18 nov. 2020Great for wearing in the summer. I recommend it for the material and comfort.",

"Très bon produit !V I. - 25 juin 2020Rien à dire si ce n'est que je le recommande vivement"**

I want only the words "Great for wearing in the summer. I recommend it for the material and comfort." and "Great for wearing in the summer. I recommend it for the material and comfort.".

Please find below the screenshot for the html of the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yGky.jpg)

Comment: Are you seriously saying you can't figure out how to do that?  You can see, I presume, that there is a pattern.  Title, user initials, date.  So, look for the date.

Comment: How do I get rid of <p style="word-wrap:break-word">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to go deeper in the css query, instead of

```
soup.select(".review.mb10-sm")
```

change it to

```
soup.select(".review.mb10-sm div p")
```

Comment: <p style="word-wrap:break-word">Great for wearing in the summer. I recommend it for the material and comfort.</p>

I get this as result. How do I get only "Great for wearing in the summer. I recommend it for the material and comfort."?

Comment: <p style="word-wrap:break-word">

Comment: you can extract the text by using .text like the one you use in your for loop

Comment: I shouldn't respond, but it irritates me that you can't figure this out.  This is absolutely basic Python string processing.  You need to do PART of this yourself.